# Model API or load bulk data?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I want to add scrapped data to my database.  I like the fact that the API enables validation but I assume that the overhead is too high.  I'm writing maybe 10k rows at a time, at most. Is that accurate?

Alright, so one other issue I was having, which was preventing me from testing this hypothesis is that I'm currently unable to import my models module.  I get an error message claiming that my DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.

my django.wsgi script does define it and it works within the context of django.  I assume that when I try to execute a python file from the command line, the .wsgi script is not run. Again, assumptions, I know.

Do I have to add my django project to my PYTHONPATH within the bashrc file to make this work?

Comment: "I assume that the overhead is too high"?  Why assume?  Why not measure?  Also.  Database data should be clean, otherwise it has little value.  I don't see how validation is optional.  Please update your question to explain what performance problems you have and why validation is optional.

Comment: Well I've cleaned the data to a large extent during the scraping process.  Maybe that's not dry.  I assume because a friend told me as much. I also thought that this would be a cut and dry question/response

Comment: "I also thought that this would be a cut and dry question/response"?  No reason why.  Without benchmark measurements, all "overhead" questions are impossible to answer.  Your form could be hellishly complex or really simple.  We don't know.

Comment: "I'm currently unable to import my models module." is unrelated to the question title.  Please fix the title and **focus** the question on the answer you accepted.

Comment: Downvoted because title doesn't match the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set your project's settings file in ~/.bashrc if you want to use it in a script.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/django/project
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
```

or

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=/path/to/django/project/settings
```